# Is it possible to integrate IBM Cognos framework manager with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, business-intelligence, cognos

The tool we are trying to integrate with vsts(Azure DevOps) is Cognos Framework Manager. Is Cognos Framework Manager anyway compatible to integrate with vsts. In what way will i be able to acheive this. I was just trying to get ideas from PowerBI to understand workflow of BI projects. But its quite different from Cognos Framework Manager. This is in regards to testing the workflow of Cognos projects & their CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Hoping to reignite this question.  @salman are you asking about using Azure DevOps to publish packages from a model.xml file in a git repo to your Cognos Analytics environment?

Comment: @dougp Yes that too, also if anyway the code checking and CI part can be done using Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1):

One of FM's selling points used to be it's native integration with source control but that feature was taken out when it was no longer in a competitors feature list.

Having said that, Framework manager is just a bunch of files. Just commit those files to a DevOps github repository using for example git command line.

With regards to automatic deployment from DevOps to your environment, you'd need to work out how to use the FM API. Some info here but I'm not going to take the time to decipher it

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dg_fm_sdk.10.2.2.doc/c_sdk_overview.html

In the very least you'd need to install FM in your DevOps deployment agent